# mobile client have no internet when connected to Wireguard server on VPS

Tags: ubuntu, vps, ubuntu-20.04, ufw, wireguard

**Hello Folks,**

I setup **Wireguard server on my VPS** too many times with different approaches and configs, yet there is no internet when I connect a client(e.g mobile/laptop) to my vps, although it connects.

My VPS is running on Ubuntu 20.

I used 2 different Tutorials/methods as below links:
https://dev.to/tangramvision/what-they-don-t-tell-you-about-setting-up-a-wireguard-vpn-1h2g
..

https://github.com/bllizard22/easy-wireguard-server .. **(my current installation)**
*(note: to avoid possible conflicts,I completely remove wireguard and iptables rules before trying a new installation)*

the problem is that clients connect to my server but no internet is available though.
I asked the support team to verify the UDP ports state. they insist that they are not blocking anything. If I allow a UDP port via UFW, it means it is fully open/useable.

How May I troubleshoot ?, how to fix this issue ?
Im not a networking pro, but I can manage to understand subjects..

thanks guys